Interleave Controller in Jmeter
While doing testing in jmeter, I add interleave controller. but in interleave controller all samplers are executed instead of executing one samplers in sequential order in every itteration. how can i fix it?
one sampler should be executed in sequential order in every itteration

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I cannot reproduce your issue, make sure to put your Samplers under the Interleave Controller so they would be the children of the controller, this way each iteration next Sampler will be executed.
Here is a demo using Dummy Sampler and __groovy() function to display the current iteration:

